# Edit a view used by a cube containing calculated columns ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to change the datasource of the view from a query that has many joins to one query with one table containing all the fields, but the original view has some calculated columns,and I want to replace these calculated with physical ones,and I can't edit the view,neither delete fields or methods.Any idea, thank you

Comment: Have you enabled Version Control? In that case check out before changing.

Comment: No,it has not to do with Version Control, anyway I used the existing methods to return the physical fields.